# Is it possible to factor out bin_op nonterminal in grammar specification?

Tags: parsing, yacc, bison

Inconvenience in specifying grammars - we cannot factor out bin_op in following example (Bison):

```
expr : expr bin_op expr ;
bin_op : Add
    | Mul
    ;
```

because of shift/reduce conflicts. Is there parsing technique or parser generator which allows such thing?

Comment: I have tagged this as homework. If not, please re-edit.

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes

Yacc has been employed to parse almost every real programming language and some other types. I'm not nearly its biggest fan but it can certainly parse that grammar or perhaps an equivalent that is written with yacc in mind.

And shift/reduce conflicts are not errors.

Comment: Equivalent - yes, that - no. It's the point of question.
Text from one pdf file on the Net (I cannot find it again):
A hint: following grammar does not work…
precedence left AND,OR;
precedence left PLUS,MINUS;
precedence left STAR,SLASH;
expr ::= expr bin_op expr;
expr ::= ID;
bin_op ::= AND|OR|PLUS|MINUS|STAR|SLASH;

Consider parser stacks:
expr

/
expr

bin_op
expr

expr
bin_op
expr

What to do if next token is PLUS?
Could shift PLUS
Could reduce expr bin_op expr
Depends on precedence of bin_op vs PLUS
Precedence has been lost